# Selected value doesn't apply for md select AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm using AngularJS Material select option and I want to set current selected value as the option. I have tried different ways and not working. This is what I tried. When user click , it should trigger the on change.

```
  <div flex>
    <md-select ng-model="$callcenterController.selectedLanguage"  ng-change="$callcenterController.languageChange($callcenterHomeController.selectedLanguage.name)" placeholder="{{$callcenterController.selectLanguageLabel}}" ng-model-options="{trackBy: 'languages.name' }"
    >
        <md-option ng-value="languages" ng-repeat="languages in $callcenterHomeController.languageList"> {{ languages.name }}</md-option>
    </md-select>
```

Comment: `md-option` itself gets selected and doesn't need the `ng-change`.
You can add the non working example here for more R&D.

Comment: I don't have any issue with ng-change. Please answer according to my question

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.languageList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "option 1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "option 2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "option 3"
    }

  ];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <link href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" layout layout-align="center center">
   <md-select ng-model="myModel" placeholder="Pick">
    <md-option ng-value="{{ languages.id }}" ng-repeat="languages in languageList"> {{ languages.name }}</md-option>
   </md-select>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You  have only changed  ng-value? I tried and still ist not working

Comment: I guess i have shared a working example. There may be some other issue.

Comment: In your example , where do you set the value ?

Comment: We don't need to apply any logic here. Normally in a drop down when you select any item it automatically select its value in the same manner `md-select` works.